# USART giving unknown values on the atmega 328p

Tags: embedded, avr, atmega, usart

I have been unable to solve a simple USART transmit/receive program. The problem is that I used this in the past and worked effortlessly but now it returns in my Linux machine question marks and in windows some boxes and Chinese characters. I don´t understand what changed. I have tried a lot of different things like changing the code and the parts but nothing seems to solve it.

I´m using a AVR atmega 328p, and a pololu usb programmer. I flashed it from the atmel studio in windows and from avrdude in linux.

Here is the code:

```c
#define F_CPU 1000000
#define BAUD 9600

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>


void init_USART(void);
void transmit_Byte(char data);
char receive_Byte(void);

int main(void)
{
    char TEST;
    init_USART();                               /* Initialize USART */

    while (1) 
    {

        TEST =  receive_Byte();
        transmit_Byte(TEST);

    }
}


void init_USART(void)
{
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;                       
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;

    #if USE_2x
        UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);
    #else
        UCSR0A &= ~(1 << U2X0);
    #endif

    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);           /* Enable USART 
                                                    transmitt/receive */
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);         /* 8 data bits, 1 stop 
                                                            bit */ 
}

void transmit_Byte(char data)
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);           /* Wait for empty 
                                                    transmit buffer */
    UDR0 = data;
}

char receive_Byte(void)
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0);
    return(UDR0);
}
```

This is my first question so I apologize in advanced if I did something wrong.

Thanks a lot for your time!

edit: I have tried a ftdi232 and a mcp2221

edit 2: [After addin UL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMB3S.png) still not as expected but got less unknown characters.

SOLVED: But I don't understand why. I changed the fuse CKDIV8 to 1 and it started working. The datasheet says it comes factory with 8 MHz clock and the CKDIV8=0 so it is set to 1 MHz. So why is it inversed? I also tried previously  `clock_prescale_set(clock_div_8);` as the datasheet suggest for prescaling and it didn't work neither.

What is the difference between setting the CLDIV8 and the avr/power.h function?

Comment: does your µC really run at 1MHz?

Comment: If so, @ 1 MHz, try to  write `#define F_CPU 1000000UL`

Comment: Yeah it is set to 1 Mhz. I tried the UL after F_CPU and BAUD and i got less unknown characters but still not what is expected i will put a photo

Comment: From latest datasheet, I read the CKDIV8 is set, so you have to set CKDIV8=1 "The device is shipped with the CKDIV8 Fuse programmed." Please edit your code above with the correct settings, so if someone comes across this page ... +1

Comment: "Note that the fuses are read as logical zero, “0”, if they are programmed" - quote from reference guide "Memory Programming->Fuse bits". CKDIV8 sets prescaler register value 8, that equals division of CLOCK by 8. I assume clock_prescale_set(clock_div_8); does the same thing, so they equal. To set CLOCK to 8Mhz you should do something like clock_prescale_set(0);